# How do you break up lines character-wise?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a big text file made up of 64 hex values.
Each line is stored one after the other; some lines are incorrectly recorded with 63 character hex values, while others are stored with 61 character hex values.

Characters-wise, I want to divide the files into 64 (Characters)-file, 63 (Characters)-file, and 61 (Characters)-file.

How can I separate them?

Comment: Please add some example input. Depending on the input, it looks like something like `awk '{print > length}'` should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `length()` function in `awk` to filter your file. Something along the lines of

```
awk 'length($0) == 61' your_input_file.txt > only_lines_with_61_chars.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with `-E`,`--extended-regexp`:

```sh
grep -E "^.{61}$" your_input_file.txt > only_lines_with_61_chars.txt
```